# passing an object as param in ng-click

Tags: angularjs

I'm using angularjs datatable, and I've added action buttons to this datatable.

I have a button which I named `Edit` so this button will call a function with the current row informations in it as following :

```
<button class="btn btn-bl btn-success btn-ef btn-ef-5 btn-ef-5b mb-10" ng-click="openEditModal('+data+')"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> <span>'+$scope.update+'</span></button>
```

which doesn't work, and this is the error I get :

> error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'Object' is unexpected,
>   expecting []] at column 23 of the expression [openEditModal([object
>   Object])] starting at [Object])].

But when I pass a param to my function as this : `ng-click="openEditModal('+data.id+')"` it works, but I want to pass the whole object.

This is the code of `openEditModal()` :

```
$scope.openEditModal = function(user) {
      $scope.user = user;
      console.log($scope.user);
      $uibModal.open({
        templateUrl: 'edit.tmpl.html',
        controller: 'EditModalInstanceCtrl',
        size: 'lg',
        resolve: {
          user: function () {
            return $scope.user;
          }
        }
      });
    };
```

and this is `EditModalInstanceCtrl` :

```
.controller('EditModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $uibModalInstance, user,$state) {
    $scope.user = user;
    // function to submit the form after all validation has occurred
    $scope.confirmEdit = function(isValid) {
      // check to make sure the form is completely valid
      if (isValid) {
        console.log('our form is amazing');
        $uibModalInstance.close();
        console.log(user);
        $state.go($state.current, {}, {reload: true});
      } else {
        console.log('form is invalid');
      }
    };
```

and this is the code of my datatable controller :

```
.controller('CandidaturesDatatableCtrl', function ($scope, DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.fromSource('http://www.filltext.com/?rows=10&id={index}&firstname={firstName}&lastname={lastName}&city={city}&contactemail={email}&message={lorem|50}&pretty=true')
      .withPaginationType('full_numbers')
      .withBootstrap()
      // Active Responsive plugin
      .withOption('responsive', true)
      .withOption('initComplete', function(settings) {
        // Recompiling so we can bind Angular directive to the DT
        $compile(angular.element('#' + settings.sTableId).contents())($scope);
      });
    vm.dtColumns = [
      DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('id').withTitle('ID'),
      DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('firstname').withTitle('First name'),
      DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('lastname').withTitle('Last name'),
      // .notVisible() does not work in this case. Use .withClass('none') instead
      DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('city').withTitle('City'),
      DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('contactemail').withTitle('Email'),
      DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('message').withTitle('Message').withClass('none'),
      DTColumnBuilder.newColumn(null).withTitle('Actions').notSortable()
        .renderWith(function(data, type, full, meta) {
          if (true) {
            return  '<button class="btn btn-bl btn-success btn-ef btn-ef-5 btn-ef-5b mb-10" ng-click="openEditModal('+data+')"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> <span>'+$scope.update+'</span></button>&nbsp;'
              + '<button class="btn btn-danger btn-rounded btn-ef btn-ef-5 btn-ef-5b mb-10" ng-click="openDeleteModal('+data.id+')"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> <span>'+$scope.delete+'</span></button>';
          } else {
            return '';
          }
        })
    ];
  });
```

so here is the scenario I want, when I click on the update button this will trigger the  `ng-click="openEditModal('+data.id+')"` and then this function will open a modal passing the user object to it, and the edit.tmpl.html will be populated with user object attributes.

## How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### **Update**

I understood the problem, you can just fix that problem just by passing `id` to popup controller while opening. In current way you are trying to pass record data to popup directly from resolve option. By having such approach could introduce data inconsistency in your application.

**Let me explain how that is possible?**

Consider a scenario where user landed on page which has the table which you are displaying & then he stays there for suppose 10 mins, thereafter he open up on record. Here we go. Suppose you followed first approach of passing whole data from that particular record. so that will pop up on page..but that data might have changed by someone. and still you are showing old data, which will cause data inconsistency in your application.

In the approach which I'm suggesting will be pretty straight forward.. you are making ajax based on id to make sure data is consistent.. so that ajax might take few milliseconds(no performance impact), so less cost for consistent application is reasonable.. I think I'm clear with my point

**Makrup**

```
ng-click="openEditModal('+data.id+')" //pass id and retrieve data again in popup controller
```

Comment: when I tried the code you gave me I get an undefined and `ng-click="openEditModal('+data.id+')` works in my case so `ng-click="openEditModal('+data+')` should work also. and when I try `ng-click="openEditModal(data.id)` I get an undefined as well so passing it directly doesn't work in my case

Comment: @AimadMAJDOU may I know why you are wrapping `data` with `+`?

Comment: I think that's the only way to do that since I have a rendered html code  inside my controller

Comment: @AimadMAJDOU oh. you are rendering HTML manually.. so I'd say that.. for popup while editing data you should pass `data.id` as you are doing there for edit..then inside a popup controller ask for data on basis of that id again

Comment: won't that be bad for performance since I already having all the data and then I ask for them again.

Comment: @AimadMAJDOU no it wouldn't.. I'll give you an example.. consider a scenario where user landed on page which has the table which you are displaying & then he stays there for suppose 10 mins, thereafter he open up on record. Here we go.. suppose you followed first approach of passing whole data from that particular record. so that will pop up on page..but that data might have changed by someone.. and still you are showing old data, which will cause data inconsistency in your application..

Comment: In the approach which I'm suggesting will be pretty straight forward.. you are making ajax based on `id` to make sure data is consistent.. so that ajax might take few milliseconds(no performance impact), so less cost for consistent application is reasonable.. I think I'm clear with my point. Thanks :-)

Comment: @AimadMAJDOU updated answer too.. I hope you are agreed & clear with what I wanted to say.. thanks :)